# I want to know the output of code

Tags: c

```
for(print("a");print("b");print("c"))
{
printf("d");
}
```

This question was asked in an interview , my answer was "abdcabdcabdc....." .
 I want to know the proper output an explanation.Please help me out.

Comment: Are those `print` calls supposed to be `printf` calls?

Comment: Anyway, what makes you think "a" would be printed more than once?

Comment: And regardless of your expectations, did you not consider running the code yourself to *see* what it prints?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the **print** in the for loop would be **printf**.

The output of this code will be

**abdcbdcbdcbdc...** infinite times.

(**a** will be printed only once as we initialize the counter in loop only once)

**EXPLANATION**

As it's a **for loop** so the execution will be in the following order.

1. Initialization
2. Conditon Check
3. Body Execution
4. Increment counter

Here in the condition there is a **printf** statement which always return the **number of characters** it prints. Here, **printf("d")** **returns 1** as it is printing only **1** character.

And in **C**, **1** is treated as **TRUE** and **0** is treated as **FALSE**.

So, here the condition is always **TRUE**, so it runs for infinite times.